# Why this functional interface is valid

Tags: java

I have found an example with java predicate functional interface:

```
BiPredicate<String, String> b1 = String::startsWith;
BiPredicate<String, String> b2 =
            (string, prefix) -> string.startsWith(prefix);
System.out.println(b1.test("chicken", "chick"));
System.out.println(b2.test("chicken", "chick"));
```

I understand how b2 works - it's clear.
How does the compiler understand how to use the b1 method? Method boolean startWith(String str) has only one parameter. String class doesn't have
boolean startWith(String srt1, String srt2) method.

Comment: It is just a shortcut, `(a,b)->a.c()` is the same thing as `ClassOfA::c`

Comment: Read about method references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Method startWith(String str) has only one parameter.

Actually `String.startsWith` has an implicit `this` parameter because you’re calling it on an *object instance*. Thus it conforms to a functional interface with two `String` parameters.

As mentioned by Giorgi, you should consult the [documentation on method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html), since there’s a lot more to this syntax, and the way it works when the name before `::` refers to an object *versus* a class name.

Briefly, there are four cases. Assuming a functional interface for a method call with two parameters `a` and `b`:

1. **`Class::staticMethod`**

   This is equivalent to `(a, b) -> Class.staticMethod(a, b)`.
2. **`object::method`**

   This is equivalent to `(a, b) -> object.method(a, b)`.
3. **`Class::method`**

   This is equivalent to `(a, b) -> a.method(b)`.
4. **`Class::new`**

   This is equivalent to `(a, b) -> new Class(a, b)`.